# can't get channel by a unqiue name twillio programmabale chat node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

//this is my code to get channel by unique name. It is not giving me any response

```js
client.chat.services(serviceSid)
        .channels({uniqueName:'demo'})
        .fetch()
        .then(channel => console.log(channel));
```

// this is form sid of channel and it is working

```js
client.chat.services(serviceSid)
        .channels('XXXXX')
        .fetch
        .then(channels=>  console.log(channel));
```

and the reponse is

```js
{
  sid: 'CH...................b1e',
  accountSid: 'AC...................b71735f',
  serviceSid: 'IS..................caa8',
  friendlyName: 'demo',
  uniqueName: 'demo',
  attributes: '{}',
  type: 'public',
  dat2020-04-21T16:54:52.000Z,
  dateUpdated: 2020-04-21T16:54:52.000Z,
  createdBy: 'system',
  membersCount: 0,
  messagesCount: 0,
  url: }
```

in the doc this written in [chaneel resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/channel-resource)
**When fetching a Channel resource, the {Sid} value can be either the sid or the unique_name of the Channel resource to fetch.**
 how will i retrive please answer ..
i need to complete this project in 3 days ...

Comment: get channel by unique name code not giving me any response and you can see there is a channel with unqiuename demo . asd repononse is also there

Comment: It's good that you comment out the sensitive part of the info. I remember that the whole thing was exposed when I first saw this post.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/channel-resource#fetch-a-channel-resource
I'm looking at these docs from twilio, and from their example, I'd try writing the code like this:

```js
client.chat.services(serviceSid)
           .channels('demo')
           .fetch()
           .then(channel => console.log(channel));
```

Instead of passing an object, simply pass a string of the `unique_name` to get the channel you're looking for.